# Android : Acess pagerAdapter layout listview with ViewPager and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have a pagerAdapter like this :

```
public class AppPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    public AppPagerAdapter(Context appcon)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.list);
    }
}
```

And in my XML is this : "pager_layout.xml"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ListView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:divider="@color/activity_background"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     </ListView>
```

And, my main fragment page is this :

```
public class Apps extends Fragment {
    public Apps() {}

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_activity, container, false);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        AppPagerAdapter appadapter = new AppPagerAdapter(getActivity());
        pager.setAdapter(appadapter);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //Access to this position list view for add adapter
                new Loading().execute; //async task to get data and add to list view from this pager
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Now, How can I access this view on screen page for adding data to this page?
I want to add data to listview of page that is selected.
Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your viewpager have 4 fragments: A,B,C,D. And you are open fragment A. Then Fragment B and D will be create automatically by Viewpager.

And if you want to add data to listView. Let see this method:

```
@Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_layout, container, false);
       ListView listView = (ListView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.list);

}
```

What is

> int position?

It is the Page that you selected - Openning.
Your above code will create 10 Page in ViewPager, each Page have the ListView. If you want to add data to this, only write more code in method

> instantiateItem()